# Spinner иконка слева

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Необходимо создать Spinner у которого иконка раскрытия списка будет слева. По этому вопросу, совсем ничего не удалось нарыть, в голову приходит только кастомное создание, но и здесь пока идей мало. Может гугл всётаки подумал об разработчиках?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел:

```
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>

                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>

            <bitmap android:gravity="left" android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_circuit"  />

        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

В этой строчке, мы задаём расположение, а с иконкой уже извращайтесь как хотите:

```
<bitmap android:gravity="left" android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_circuit"  />
```

P.S. Вот эта строчка, через фигуры задаётокантовку

```
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
```

**Важно**, если нам необходимо добавить окантовку к spinner, то как и следствие необходимо будет добавить иконку, ибо устанавливаемый нами background для spinner-a, полностью перекрывает всё поле, в независимость от используемого цвета (прозрачности) в нашей окантовке.